# how to confirm a file is a picture file with java language?

Tags: java, image, confirm

I want to know how can I use java to confirm a file is a picture file.

I have tried the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    // get image format in a file
    File file = new File("C:/Users/dell、/Desktop/4.xlsx");

    // create an image input stream from the specified fileDD
    ImageInputStream iis = null;
    try {
        iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // get all currently registered readers that recognize the image format
    Iterator<ImageReader> iter = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);

    if (!iter.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Not a picture file");
        throw new RuntimeException("No readers found! Unable to read the uploaded file");
    }

    // get the first reader
    ImageReader reader = iter.next();

    try {
        System.out.println("Format: " + reader.getFormatName());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // close stream
    if (iis != null){
        try {
            iis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                iis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work perfectly! It shows an exception once the file is not a picture file, so I want to find a better way.

Comment: Putting your email id openly is best way to invite for spam. Please don't post things which are not related to question, we don't send solutions to any email, please read Help Center to know how to ask questions.

Comment: There are hundreds of difference picture formats, which of those do you want to recognize? Generally, catching the exception and by that know that it is not a picture file can be a valid option.

Comment: Call an external program to check it, such as ImageMagik.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many image extensions. Maybe the best way to validate if a file is an image, is using Regular Expressions. Something like this...

```
([^\s]+(\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp|MORE|IMAGE|EXTENSIONS))$)
```

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-image-file-extension-with-regular-expression/) is a complete example of the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ImageIO#read`.

```
public static boolean isPictureFile(File file){
    try{
        return ImageIO.read(file) != null;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Basically, the method `ImageIO.read(File)` will return a `BufferedImage` object when it successfully read the image file, a null otherwise. All we have to do is to let `ImageIO` read the file and check if it returns a null or not, and if there it throws an exception for whatever reason, we can safely assume the file is not a picture file.